# Delivering css via controller doesn't work in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and I have a problem to set the layout for my web views.
Because the user has the possibility to select the desired layout in the backend, the corresponding css file is delivered by a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/web")
public class LayoutController {

    private UiLayoutSettings settings;

    @Autowired
    public LayoutController(SettingsService settingsService) {

        settings = settingsService.getSettings().getUiLayoutSettings();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/style.css", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/css")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSelectedLayout() {

        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.getResource("static/css/" + settings.getFileName());

        String text = "";
        String line = "";

        try {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text += line + "\n";
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return text;
    }

}
```

If I call the address

```
mydomain.com/web/style.css
```

in my browser, I get a response with the correct content.

Now i configured my jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="uv" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<html>

<head>
<uv:head/>
</head>
```

And my head.tag loks like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
<title>My app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/style.css" />
```

And finally this is my css:

```
@import "fonts.css";
@import "colors.css";
@import "actions.css";
@import "print.css";
@import "error.css";
```

Now I open my application in the browser and the layout is completely lost. I see a kind of text-only version.

Comment: And where do the other CSS files come from?

Comment: The other files are stored under /src/main/resources/static/css

Comment: That's probably your problem. The URL you specify is `/web/style.css`. So all CSS files you import are relative to that path. But for the content that you have in `/src/main/resources/static/css` the URL will be `/css/...`. You might want to check your browser network tab to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Ok, that sounds logic. And what would be a good way to solve it?

Comment: You need to either specify the URLs in your imports to be relative to the URL of the CSS file (e.g. @import "../css/fonts.css";) or move your CSS files into `/src/main/resources/static/web`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!